# Qt and error handling strategy

Tags: c++, qt, exception

Actually, I do understand major pros and cons of using exceptions. And I use them in my projects by default as error-handling strategy.
But now I'm starting a Windows CE project with Qt library, and I see that Qt creators refused to use exceptions in the class hierarchy.

So, if I use exceptions I will need to carefully translate them to and from error codes (or some objects, or just swallow) on my/Qt code bounds. Otherwise, I can refuse to use exceptions in my code and switch to some other strategy.

What would be the best error handling strategy in my case - to use exceptions or to use error-codes, or etc...?
Do you have experience with Qt development and what error handling strategy did you use?

Answer (score 9):

Override QApplication::notify() and handle exceptions there (not 100% on the return value). You can "throw" exceptions from signal handlers but they don't get propagated to Qt in this way.

```
bool
notify(QObject * rec, QEvent * ev)
{
  try
  {
    return QApplication::notify(rec,ev);
  }
  catch(my::Exception & e)
  {
    QMessageBox::warning(0,
                         tr("An error occurred"),
                         e.message());
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    QMessageBox::warning(0,
                         tr("An unexpected error occurred"),
                         tr("This is likely a bug."));
  }
  return false;
```

Comment: So, this method will allow us to throw exceptions from event handlers. But what about slots (with direct connection and queued connection)?

Comment: please do not throw from slots - unless you make sure QMetaObject::activate is exception safe (it is not in 4.8.2) but has been fixed at a later point for 4.8

Comment: Yes you can catch errant exceptions from event handlers like that, but is this solution is implying that the OP should reinterpret QT's error codes into exceptions and use the above method to catch them? I think @AlexChe was asking for advice on an overall error handling strategy?

Answer (score 0):

Throwing exceptions out of an event handler is not supported in Qt. Avoid that, and there should not be any problem with exceptions.

Comment: Does cheez say it is actually supported?

Comment: No, not supported. Just that you can use them at your own risk.