# How can I profile events in a PyQt application?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, profiling, timing

This [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097861/qt-measure-event-handling-time/15102642) seems to provide a really clean way to monitor the duration of all Qt events in C++. I'm interested in doing something similar in Python for a PyQt5 application.

The high level goal is to have profiling we can optionally enable to get hard numbers for what is making the application feel slow. How long did the paint take? How long did that mouse click take? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just pythonify the C++ code in the linked answer:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QElapsedTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton

class MyApplication(QApplication):

    t = QElapsedTimer()

    def notify(self, receiver, event):
        self.t.start()
        ret = QApplication.notify(self, receiver, event)
        if(self.t.elapsed() > 10):
            print(f"processing event type {event.type()} for object {receiver.objectName()} " 
                  f"took {self.t.elapsed()}ms")
        return ret


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApplication([])
    ....
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Wow that works. I'm new to PyQT and I didn't see "notify" in the source. I wasn't sure you could override a random C++ method like that. Works great, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the source of QApplication? notify() is a method of QObject so you wouldn't find it in the source code of QApplication. The API of PyQt5 follows that of the C++ version of Qt quite closely. So much so that I almost always use the official documentation of Qt when I need to look something up for PyQt5.

Comment: I didn't see a notify() method in all of QtPy5 source. I gather now though PyQt5 exposes the C++ classes/methods, but that doesn't mean it contains Python versions of them. Which makes sense. Anyway this works great.

Answer (score 2):

Reusing the same `QElapsedTimer` instance is a bad idea because `notify` may be called inside of the method itself. In that case `start` will be called again, which results in incorrect shorter time measurements. Also, I would expect that to cause problems if you are using threads. To avoid all that I would make use of local variables and use `time.monotonic` instead of `QElapsedTimer` to measure the time difference.

I ran occasionally into exceptions when I tried calling `receiver.objectName()` after `notify()`. Qt complained that `receiver` had been deleted.

This works for me:

```
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton

class MyApplication(QApplication):

    def notify(self, receiver, event):
        eventType = event.type()
        receiverName = receiver.objectName()
        start = time.monotonic()
        ret = QApplication.notify(self, receiver, event)
        end = time.montonic()
        elapsedMSec = (end - start) * 1000
        if(elapsedMSec > 10):
            print(f"processing event type {eventType} for object {receiverName} took {elapsedMSec} msec")
        return ret


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApplication([])
    ....
    app.exec()
```